# Como subtrair duas datas usando Ruby e a biblioteca Time?

Tags: ruby, time, irb

Esse é o código:

```
require 'time'
t  = Time.parse('2016-04-18') #data de ontém
t2 = Time.now #data atual
t3 = t2 - t # subtração das duas variáveis(datas) acima
puts Time.at(t3) #resultado da subtração
```

Nesse caso o resultado deveria ser um dia e algumas horas, mas o programa me retorna essa data: "1970-01-02 08:00:42 -0300". Não sei onde estou errando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oque acontece é que, Ao subtrair `t - t2`, ruby retornara um float de diferença, e ao chamar `Time.at(t3)`, ele converterá aquela diferença em uma data compatível. Não exatamente, ao tempo passado.

Oque você deve estar procurando pode ser isso:

```
require 'time'
tempo_atras  = Time.parse('2016-04-18')

agora = Time.now

dias = (     agora.day   -   tempo_atras.day  ).to_s
horas = (    agora.hour  -   tempo_atras.hour ).to_s
minutos = (  agora.min   -   tempo_atras.min  ).to_s
segundos = ( agora.sec   -   tempo_atras.sec  ).to_s
meses = (    agora.mon   -   tempo_atras.mon  ).to_s
anos = (     agora.year  -   tempo_atras.year ).to_s

puts *["dias: "+dias, "horas: "+horas, "minutos: "+minutos, "segundos: "+segundos, "meses: "+meses, "anos: "+anos]
```

Comment: Perfeito! Era exatamente isso!. Muito obrigado!

Comment: @Constantinologia Eu que agradeço a escolha ;)